# Find line tangent of matrix loaded from file

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to write a script that creates a matrix comprised of two lines with three real numbers on each line (in the range of -1 to 3) and saves it to a file.

I think this can be done by something like:

```
line(rand(3,2),rand(3,2))
```

Then I want to write another script that loads the file into a matrix and computes the tangent of every element in the matrix.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let's first make random real numbers within the range

I'll make a data variable first

```
data=(3+1)*rand(2,3)-1;
```

then save it to the .dat file

```
save testtan.dat data -ascii
```

now in two steps I'll simply load it into a matrix and take the tan of every element and store it in `mytangents`

```
load testtan.dat

mytangents=tan(load('testtan.dat'))
```